# Flutter - Local Notifications - Trace Error

Tags: android, flutter, notifications, android-notifications

I'm new to Flutter and started to implement the flutter_local_notifications plugin to display local notifications.

Ref: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications

The implementation was done as described as the readme page and I can get it working in a blank project, but when I use the same code in my current project, the error bellow is always displayed when the notification "flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show" is issued.

There isn't any argument null, and also all other project files was configured as the readme (build.gradle, manifest, proguard). Tried to change all those made no difference.
What are the steps required to find the root of the problem on the specif project that I working with?

**The error:**

```
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(14122): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(14122): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.ComponentName android.content.Intent.getComponent()' on a null object reference
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(14122):   at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.getMainActivityClass(FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.java:477)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(14122):   at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.createNotification(FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.java:131)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(14122):   at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.showNotification(FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.java:688)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(14122):   at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.java:827)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(14122):   at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.onMethodCall(FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.java:750)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(14122):   at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:230)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(14122):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(14122):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:650)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(14122):   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(14122):   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:325)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(14122):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(14122):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6521)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(14122):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(14122):   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(14122):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

**Code:**

```
FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

_initNotification() async {
   var initializationSettingsAndroid = AndroidInitializationSettings('app_icon');
   var initializationSettingsIOS = IOSInitializationSettings(
       requestSoundPermission: true,
       requestBadgePermission: true,
       requestAlertPermission: true,
       onDidReceiveLocalNotification: _onDidReceiveLocalNotification
   );
   var initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(initializationSettingsAndroid, initializationSettingsIOS);
   await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
       onSelectNotification: (String payload) async {
         if (payload != null) {
           print('notification payload: ' + payload);
         }});
  }

  Future _onDidReceiveLocalNotification(int id, String title, String body, String payload) async {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
        title: Text(title),
        content: Text(body),
        actions: [
          FlatButton(
            child: Text('Ok'),
            onPressed: () {Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/messages");},
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  _display() async {
    var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'id', 'name', 'desc', importance: Importance.High, priority: Priority.High,);
    var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics = IOSNotificationDetails();
    var platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(androidPlatformChannelSpecifics, iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(0, 'title', 'body', platformChannelSpecifics, payload: 'item x');
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _initNotification();
    super.initState();
  }
```

**Note:**

- The function _display() is called in a Raised button inside Scaffold. Code is omitted for simplification.
- The error is thrown when "flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show" is called.

Comment: Please include the code that is causing this error.

Comment: Please include the code where you have initialized the flutter_local_notification instance. I have got this error a while ago and then I got to know that  I haven't initialized it correctly. I was missing the app_icon.

Comment: Code of the plugin included. Please let me know if code of other project files are need (build.gradle, MainActivity, or other). @JagrajSingh, missing the app_icon throws a different exception.

Comment: Even tried to manually pass all possible arguments to AndroidNotificationDetails(), but result is the same, even passing directly 'icon' and 'largeIcon' to it.

Comment: do you have an asset named ```app_icon``` in your ```drawable``` or ```resources``` ? If not,  change ```app_icon``` to ```ic_launcher``` and see if that works.

Comment: Yes, I do. Already tried changing name and I can see that it can see the file, otherwise it causes an different error message.

Comment: Did you find any solution?